# I want a accordian-style hover on the images in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, accordion

Here I have created an application that contains 3 images. If you hover on that, it should be popping up like accordian, but now when it's popping up, it hides the rest of the images. So how to do the accordian effect means when the first image pops up, the rest of the image shrinks like in accordian, and the middle image popup should maintain the flow like the last and first images are shrunk, and the popup direction should be maintained with spread from middle to left and right, not left to right, and the right picture popup should maintain flow like right to left. So how to achieve that? If there is any suggestion to do that, can you please tell me?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [hoveredIndex, setHoveredIndex] = useState(null);

  const imageUrls = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581551-867e0b208bd1?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697219590638-d2db7748802e?q=80&w=1452&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682686581427-7c80ab60e3f3?q=80&w=1470&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`ctr-accordion ${index === hoveredIndex ? "active" : ""}`}
          onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredIndex(index)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredIndex(null)}
        >
          <div className="tab">
            <img src={imageUrl} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and css code is

```
.App {
  display: flex;
}

.ctr-accordion {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.ctr-accordion:first-child .tab {
  right: 0;
}

.ctr-accordion:last-child .tab {
  left: 0;
}

.ctr-accordion.active .tab {
  width: 93%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ctr-accordion.active .tab img {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

and codesandbox like is
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/laughing-gauss-n4f84j?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C39